# Delta Epsilon Understanding

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I have a problem which states:

Let $f(x)=4x-2$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

I must find a $\delta>0$ s.t. $0<|x-1|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-2|<\epsilon$.

How can I solve a problem such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways.  Directly forward, and backwords.

Forward:  Just keep asking yourself: If $|x-1| \le \delta$, what does that say about $4x -2$ and $2$.

$|x - 1| \le \delta \implies$

$-\delta < x - 1 < \delta \implies$

$1 - \delta < x < 1 + \delta \implies$

$4 - 4\delta < 4x < 4 + 4\delta \implies$

$2 - 4\delta < 4x - 2 < 2 + 4\delta \implies$

$2 - 4\delta < f(x) < 2 + 4\delta \implies$

$-4\delta < f(x) - 2 < 4\delta \implies $

$|f(x) -2| < 4\delta$.

So if $\epsilon = 4\delta$ or $\delta = \epsilon /4$ then $|x-1| < \delta \implies |f(x) -2 | \epsilon$

Backwards:  Keep asking yourself, what *would* imply $|f(x)-2| < \epsilon$

$|f(x)-2| < \epsilon \Leftarrow$

$-\epsilon < f(x) -2 < \epsilon \Leftarrow$

$2 - \epsilon < f(x) < 2 + \epsilon \Leftarrow$

$2 - \epsilon < 4x - 2 < 2 + \epsilon \Leftarrow$

$4 - \epsilon < 4x < 4 + \epsilon \Leftarrow$

$1 - \epsilon/4 < x < 1 + \epsilon/4 \Leftarrow$

$-\epsilon/4 < x - 1 < \epsilon/4 \Leftarrow$

$|x - 1|< \epsilon/4 \Leftarrow$

$|x-1| < \delta = \epsilon/4$

So if $\delta = \epsilon/4$ then $|x-1| \delta \implies |f(x) -2| < \epsilon$.

Comment: this is absurd.

Comment: Why is it absurd

Comment: That such detail is required.

Comment: I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed so it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ then $|f(x)-2|=|4x-2-2|=|4x-4|=4|x-1|$ select $\delta = \epsilon / 4$, then $|f(x)-2| < \epsilon $ whenever $|x-1| < \delta$.

Comment: What other deltas will work for this problem?

Comment: for any $\epsilon >$ that you select if you choose $\delta \leq \epsilon / 4$ works.

Comment: So choices like $\epsilon/4$, $\epsilon/2$, $\epsilon$? They all satisfy it?

Comment: hmmmm is that what the inequality i wrote says?

Comment: If $\delta = \epsilon/2$ the $|x-1| < \delta \implies |f(x) - 2| < 2\epsilon$ which doesn't quite work.  But if it's true for $2\epsilon$ common sense says it will be true by dividing $\delta$ to $\epsilon /4$.  Any thing smaller will work too.

Comment: If it is true for $2\epsilon$, $\epsilon/2$ is smaller than $2\epsilon$, so what you are saying is in a set of numbers everything will be correct given that $2\epsilon$ is the largest number in that set?

Answer (score 0):

$f (x)-2=4 (x-1) $.

We look for $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-1|<\delta\implies 4|x-1|<\epsilon $$

or
$$|x-1|<\delta\implies |x-1|<\frac {\epsilon}{4} $$

a $\delta\leq \frac {\epsilon}{4} $ works.

Comment: Is it really yours.

Comment: @Donnie That is exactly what i wrote.

Comment: Goodnight everybody on earth.